# IBM Clearcase CM API Provider Instantiation throws Exception "Cannot instantiate protocol provider: cqjniproxy (Not found in java.library.path)"

Tags: clearcase, instantiation, java.library.path

I started coding a test client with CM API recently from my desktop.
While trying to retrieve the provider, it throws this exception:

**Code line**:

StpProvider provider = (StpProvider) ProviderFactory.createProvider(CcProvider.PROVIDER_CLASS, callback);

PROVIDER_CLASS is "com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.StpProviderImpl"

**Exception**:

...CRVAP0055E (internal-error):  The attempt to instantiate the domain subprovider 'com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cq.CqJniSubprovider' threw an exception. See nested exceptions for details.
    ...**CRVAP0049E (internal-error):  Cannot instantiate protocol provider: cqjniproxy (Not found in java.library.path)** 
      ...java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.realException(StpExceptionImpl.java:493)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.(StpExceptionImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.(StpExceptionImpl.java:538)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.CoreProvider.(CoreProvider.java:2879)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.CoreProvider.(CoreProvider.java:2772)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.StpProviderImpl.(StpProviderImpl.java:36)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.StpProviderImpl.(StpProviderImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at javax.wvcm.ProviderFactory.createProvider(ProviderFactory.java:93)
    at web.mrs.cmapi.Main.getCCProvider(Main.java:53)
    at web.mrs.cmapi.Main.main(Main.java:31)

I have found few pages on IBM website that mention if any other resources like BIRT or CQ Reporting server is already using CM API provider, then I will get this exception, but as I am currently testing it on my desktop, no such instances are running (unless i am missing something).

Below links has this information:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014430264

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577252

Our current clearcase/Clearquest version installed is 8.0.0.10

I truly appreciate all the help anyone can provide, as this will be very useful in fixing several issues we currently face with cleartool from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The technote you mention states:

#### CRVAP0049E Cannot instantiate protocol provider: cqjniproxy (Not found in java.library.path)

> This error occurs when two different web applications attempt to access ClearQuest using the JNI adapter of the Change Management (CM) API
>
> For example, if both BIRT and the ClearQuest Report Server for Crystal Reports are deployed to the same web server, only one of the server applications can run reports that use a Change Management API JNI data source (whichever connects first until profile restart).

In your case, you might need to install, as [in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/152110/unable-to-access-clearquest-database-from-rational-insight-dataservices-1111), the ClearQuest Adapter and ClearQuest Client libraries: see "[Creating Rational ClearQuest and Rational RequisitePro shared libraries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rentrpt/v1r1m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.raer.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_postinstall_rids_sharedlibs.html)"

Maybe there is an option in the ClearTeam server to specify that you are not using (and don't need) ClearQuest at all.

As the [OP Karteek Dasari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4012224/karteek-dasari) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689009/ibm-clearcase-cm-api-provider-instantiation-throws-exception-cannot-instantiate/25689207#comment52919694_25689207):

> the root cause [is] an additional 'CCRC WAN Server' needed to be installed for Clearcase client, which provides additional jars which are needed for the provider to instantiate.
> Also, the provider class will be `NETWORK_PROVIDER_CLASS`.

See:

- "[Installing CCRC WAN server](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_install_ccrc_wan_svr.htm)"
- "[How to access a web, dynamic or snapshot view with Rational ClearCase CM API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21382733)":

> ClearCase 8 : CCRC view

```
ProviderFactory.createProvider(CcProvider.NETWORK_PROVIDER_CLASS , callback);
```

> ClearCase 8 : Dynamic view

```
ProviderFactory.createProvider(CcProvider.LOCAL_PROVIDER_CLASS , callback);
```

Comment: I found the root cause to be an additional 'CCRC WAN Server' needed to be installed for Clearcase client, which provides additional jars which are needed for the provider to instantiate. Also, the provider class will be NETWORK_PROVIDER_CLASS.

Comment: @KarteekDasari Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility. I have also added IBM docs and technotes to illustrate those parameters.